# specific sort and direction routes in cakephp

Tags: sorting, cakephp, routes

I looked around to find answers and though I found topics about the routes, none of the answers I found worked in this case. So here I go, trying to explain my problem =]

### Background information

I'm making a website in Cakephp for an estate agent. On this website you have the possibility to sort houses based on the *street*, *publish date* and *price*.

### What I want

I want to change these current urls:
*websitename.nl/houses/index/page:4/sort:street/direction:desc*
*websitename.nl/houses/index/sort:street/direction:desc/page:4*

to something like: 
*websitename.nl/houses/street/descending/4*
*websitename.nl/houses/price/ascending/4*

Street/price and descending/ascending will be translated to dutch.

### What I already tried

I tried to add this in routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/huizenaanbod/datum/aflopend/:page', array('controller' => 'houses', 'action' => 'index', 'sort'=>'published', 'direction' => 'desc'), array('page' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/huizenaanbod/datum/oplopend/:page', array('controller' => 'houses', 'action' => 'index', 'sort'=>'published', 'direction' => 'asc'), array('page' => '[0-9]+'));
```

But it ignored the desc and only the asc worked.. So I tried to add this at the index.ctp:

```
if((!empty($this->params['sort']) && $this->params['sort'] == "published") && $this->params['direction'] == 'desc'){
    echo $this->Paginator->sort('published', 'datum', array('direction' => 'asc', 'escape' => false));
} else {
    echo $this->Paginator->sort('published', 'datum', array('direction' => 'desc', 'escape' => false));
}
```

And eventhough the url does change now, the results of the sort are still ordered ASC.

So my question is:
**How can I make an url in routes, combined with :page, for a specific sort and direction?**

If you need more information, let me know.

And thank you in advance =]

Answer (score 0):

you better look at other web agencies web site to see how they do the filtering. look at the link below see how the parameters is passed.. e.g.

> http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E92826&insId=1&radius=0.0&displayPropertyType=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=3&minPrice=&maxPrice=&retirement=&partBuyPartRent=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false

Now lets get back to you question.. for passing all the parameters you need to use /** e.g.

```
Router::connect(
    '/action_name/**', //once you requesting rather than star you need to put your parameters 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'show')
);
//www.exsmple.com/action_name/parameters here...
```

[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes)

you can also customize your pagination class [from here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-PaginatorHelper.html#136-171)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply Isaac. I already saw the part you posted but sadly that's not what I need. As cakephp stated about the /** _This is useful when you want to use an argument that included a / in it_  And that's not the case since there is no / in that part of the url :(

Comment: my pleasure ... Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, pushed the enter button too soon ^^' didn't know it would post my reaction right away. Had to edit my post since I wasn't done typing yet :x